# Align text to bottom right of padding in div

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I'm new here and just started out studying HTML and CSS.

I'm trying to align the "3%" text so that it pushes up to the bottom right INSIDE the padded area.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zHPW.png

I've found results here on how to do it in a div which involved something along the lines of:

```
.parent div{
    position: relative;
}

.child div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

It worked well but unfortunately it aligned the text to the bottom right of the entire div and I only want it right up against the padded area.

I've included a picture of the problem and the HTML and CSS for that section. I'm also using Bootstrap and their cards utilities if that makes any difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 14rem; height: 7rem;">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="bump">
              <span class="overview_pageviews">Page Views</span>
              <img src="images/icon-facebook.svg" class="icon" alt="" style="float: right"><br>
            </div>
            <h4>87</h4>
            <span class="green_font" style="float: right;"><img src="images/icon-up.svg" alt="">3%</span>
          </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block{
    width: 14rem;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: rgba(240, 243, 250,.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px

}

.bump{
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.overview_pageviews{
    font-size: .8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.overview h4{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with [`flexbox`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)**. All you have to do is to **wrap your lower elements with a `div` and then add `d-flex` to the wrapping element and set the `justify-content` attribute to `space-between`** (Equivalent class in bootstrap is [`justify-content-between`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content)). And the last thing you should consider to **make `3%` element exactly align with the bottom of `87` is to use `align-items` attribute with a value of `center`** ([`align-items-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-items)). Also, you can use [`align-self`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-self) as an alternative way to do this and add it to your individual desired element.

So your final code should be like this:

```css
.block {
  width: 14rem;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: rgba(240, 243, 250, 0.6);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bump {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.overview_pageviews {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.overview h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="card border-0" style="width: 14rem; height: 7rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="bump">
        <span class="overview_pageviews">Page Views</span>
        <img src="images/icon-facebook.svg" class="icon" alt="" style="float: right"><br>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h4>87</h4>
        <span class="green_font"><img src="images/icon-up.svg" alt="">3%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! Was wondering if I got my problem across properly. 

I will give your solution a go and see what up.

Comment: @kalihix I'm glad it helps, you can mark it as an answer by using the grey mark (tick) icon beside the answer. For more information, you can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).